# Why is the expected value of the score function 0?

Tags: integration, statistics, parameter-estimation

I am currently learning about the Cramér-Rao bound. According to the lecture, $\mathbb{E}_\vartheta [U_\vartheta(X_1)] = 0$, where $\vartheta$ is a parameter, $X_1$ is a random variable with density $f(x, \vartheta)$ and $U_\vartheta(X_1)$ is the score function
$$U_\vartheta(X_1) := \frac{\partial \log f (X_1, \vartheta)}{\partial \vartheta}$$

We have 4 regularization constraints, but for this question I think we only need (R4):

(R4) $\int f(x, \vartheta) dx$ may be differentiated under the integral sign twice

I don't unterstand the first part of the proof:

> From $\int_{-\infty}^{+ \infty} f(x, \vartheta) = 1$ follows with (R4):
>
> $$\int_{-\infty}^{+ \infty} \frac{\partial f(x, \vartheta)}{\partial \vartheta} dx = 0$$

Why is that equal to 0?

Comment: English is not my mother tongue and the lecture is in German, not in English. So I'm pretty sure some things (especially R4) should be written in another way, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 1):

**(R4)** gives that you can differentiate with respect to the parameters $\vartheta$, together with the others regularization constraints, we have:

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^{+ \infty} f(x, \vartheta)\text{d}x &= 1\\
\implies\partial_{\vartheta} \Big(\int_{-\infty}^{+ \infty} f(x, \vartheta)\text{d}x\Big) &= \partial_{\vartheta} (1)\\
\implies\int_{-\infty}^{+ \infty} \frac{\partial f(x, \vartheta)}{\partial \vartheta} \text{d}x &= 0 
\end{align*}